# Passing ArrayList<CustomObject> to another activity, getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass an ArrayList of objects from one activity to another using the Parcelable interface, but am consistently getting a NullPointerException when I enter the activity to which I am passing my ArrayList.

**Vitamin.java** - defines an object with a string and two String[] arrays, implements Parcelable

**HealthBenefits.java** - Displays a list of strings. When a string is selected, the list of Vitamin objects is searched and the objects containing the selected string are put into another ArrayList. This ArrayList is then passed via putParcelableArrayListExtra to the VitaminDisplay activity.

**VitaminDisplay.java** - Displays a list of strings corresponding to the names of the vitamins which are passed to the activity.

**Vitamin.java**

```
public class Vitamin implements Parcelable{

String theName;
String[] theFoods, theBenefits;

public Vitamin(String name, String[] benefits, String[] foods)
{
    theName = name;
    theBenefits = benefits;
    theFoods = foods;
}

private Vitamin(Parcel in){
    theName = in.readString();
    ArrayList<String> tempBenefits = new ArrayList<String>();
    tempBenefits = (ArrayList<String>) in.readSerializable();
    ArrayList<String> tempFoods = new ArrayList<String>();
    tempFoods = (ArrayList<String>) in.readSerializable();

    //convert from ArrayList<String> to String[]
    theBenefits = new String[tempBenefits.size()];
    theFoods = new String[tempFoods.size()];
    theBenefits = tempBenefits.toArray(theFoods);
    theFoods = tempFoods.toArray(theFoods);
}

public String getName(){
    return theName;
}

public String[] getBenefit(){
    return theBenefits;
}

public String[] getFoods(){
    return theFoods;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    out.writeString(theName);
    out.writeStringArray(theBenefits);
    out.writeStringArray(theFoods);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vitamin> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vitamin>() {
    public Vitamin createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Vitamin(in);
    }

    public Vitamin[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Vitamin[size];
    }
};
}
```

**HealthBenefits.java**

```
public class HealthBenefits extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.health_benefits_layout);

    ListView benefits = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    benefits.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.benefits, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    benefits.setAdapter(aa);

    final ArrayList<Vitamin> vitamins = new ArrayList<Vitamin>();
    String[] foods1 = {"Pork", "Whole grain", "Legumes", "Nuts and seeds"};
    String[] vitaBenefits1 = {"Improve nerve function", "Improve metabolism"};
    vitamins.add(new Vitamin("Vitamin B1", vitaBenefits1, foods1));

    String[] vitaBenefits13 = {"Improve circulatory function"};
    String[] foods13 = {"Leafy green vegetables"};
    vitamins.add(new Vitamin("Vitamin K", vitaBenefits13, foods13));

        //...more vitamin objects added to the list, omitted for brevity

    benefits.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            ArrayList<Vitamin> listToDisplay = new ArrayList<Vitamin>();

            if(position == 1)
            {
            //code specific to first list item    
                    for(int i = 0;i < vitamins.size();i++){
                        if(vitamins.get(i).getBenefit().equals("Improve immune system")) {
                            listToDisplay.add(vitamins.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), VitaminDisplay.class);
                     myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("VITAMINS", listToDisplay);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if(position == 2)
            {
            //code specific to 2nd list item    
            }
        }
  });
}
}
```

**VitaminDisplay.java**

```
public class VitaminDisplay extends Activity{

ArrayList<Vitamin> vitaminsList;
ArrayList<String> displayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.health_benefits_layout);

    vitaminsList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("VITAMINS");
            displayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0;i < vitaminsList.size();i++){
        displayList.add(vitaminsList.get(i).getName());
        Log.d("VitaminDisplay", vitaminsList.get(i).getName());
    }

    //displayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //displayList.add("test");

    ListView benefits = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    benefits.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, displayList);
    benefits.setAdapter(aa);
}

}
```

I believe the exception may be from how I have implemented the Parcelable class in Vitamin.java, but I have yet to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Here's the full logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.heartsmart/com.example.heartsmart.VitaminDisplay}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:60)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2139)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.example.heartsmart.Vitamin.<init>(Vitamin.java:23)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.example.heartsmart.Vitamin.<init>(Vitamin.java:20)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.example.heartsmart.Vitamin$1.createFromParcel(Vitamin.java:62)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.example.heartsmart.Vitamin$1.createFromParcel(Vitamin.java:1)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2103)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Bundle.containsKey(Bundle.java:271)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.example.heartsmart.VitaminDisplay.onCreate(VitaminDisplay.java:23)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-21 21:55:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What line generates the NPE?

Comment: editted to show the exception: 04-21 20:59:26.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.heartsmart/com.example.heartsmart.VitaminDisplay}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: There is more to the logcat. Something like `Caused by com.your.package.name(java line number)` this will tell you what line number the exception is occurring at

Comment: Edited with the full logcat if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top of my head. One thing is missing when you try to get array.

Instead of doing

```
vitaminsList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("VITAMINS");
```

try

```
vitaminsList = getIntent().getExtras.getParcelableArrayList("VITAMINS");
```

you should add more checks like...

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null && b.containsKey("VITAMINS")){
   vitaminsList = b.getParcelableArrayList("VITAMINS");
}
```

Comment: Changed, thanks. Still receiving the NullPointerException unfortunately though.

Comment: Debug to make sure your your array list is not null before you pass it to 2nd activity.

Comment: Checked the array by adding a couple of elements to it before passing and printed the size to the log. It's not null unfortunately, I was hoping that would be the solution.

Comment: In your Intent try passing your Activity Context instead of your view context.

Comment: Thanks, how do I pass the activity context? It's not immediately obvious to me after a google search.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing your arrays using `Parcel.writeStringArray` but trying to read them using `Parcel.readSerializable`. Change your `Vitamin` constructor to match  how you write `writeToParcel`. This should do it:

```
private Vitamin(Parcel in){
    theName = in.readString();
    theBenefits = in.createStringArray();
    theFoods = in.createStringArray();
}
```

Alternatively, modify `writeToParcel` to write the string arrays as `Serializable` objects. Or you could put the arrays into a `Bundle` and write and then read the bundle.

Even better, switch to using `ArrayList<String>`, which I think provides better support for this.

Answer (score 1):

There could be more and this might not be the problem you are currently having but this is a problem. In `VitaminDisplay` you never initialize your `ArrayList` before trying to add to it

```
ArrayList<String> displayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.health_benefits_layout);

vitaminsList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("VITAMINS");
for(int i = 0;i < vitaminsList.size();i++){
    displayList.add(vitaminsList.get(i).getName());   // displayList isn't initialized
```

Change it to

```
ArrayList<String> displayList = new ArrayList<String>();  // Change this here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.health_benefits_layout);

vitaminsList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("VITAMINS");
for(int i = 0;i < vitaminsList.size();i++){
    displayList.add(vitaminsList.get(i).getName());
```

Comment: ah, that's embarrassing. Thanks for the catch

Comment: I'm still receiving the NullPointerException unfortunately even with this fix.

Comment: Then you need to post the full logcat so we know which line. I can make guesses but that was the only obvious one